# Rails filtering specific headers for request object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, postman

Since devise doesn't support token authentication, I've been following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6) to develop my own authentication system. However, I noticed that if I pass `authentication_token` or `access_token` headers in my request, they probably get filtered in rails. Meaning that something like `p request.headers['authentication_token']` and almost any of their variation returns nil. However, header named `:omfgwork` works. Can someone please explain why does this happen and link me to a source where I can find the list of filtered headers?

EDIT- I'm using postman to send the requests to my rails app. [image: Postman]

EDIT 2

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  protected

  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    100.times {print '|'}
    p ''
    p request.headers[:uid] # works
    p request.headers[:authentication_token] # returns nil
    p request.headers[:access_token] # returns nil
    p request.headers['omfgwork'] # works
    p request.headers[:omfgwork] # works
    100.times {print '|'}
    p ''

    # return if request.headers[:uid].nil? or request.headers[:access_token].nil?

    user_email = request.headers[:uid].presence
    user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

    # Notice how we use Devise.secure_compare to compare the token
    # in the database with the token given in the params, mitigating
    # timing attacks.
    if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, request.headers[:access_token])
      sign_in user, store: false
    end
  end

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    policy_name = exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore
    render json: "#{policy_name}: Not authorized", status: :forbidden
  end

end
```

In articles controller:

```
before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're making this request?

Comment: @RyanBigg updated the question!

Comment: You are using devise and building your own authentication?

Comment: @jdgray only for token auth, as linked in the guide. Its not a lot more than what there is already, just few tweaks.

Comment: Can you update with your relevant controllers?

Comment: @jdgray Quite frankly the tweaks for token authentication are only on the model for generating new token after every request. The app itself is a test application for the authentication process and has nothing extra apart from devise and pundit.

Comment: Based on that guide you are following they are using `ApplicationController`, so you aren't using the guide?

Comment: @jdgray I added the code

Comment: @AkashAgarwal what does `p request.headers.keys` output

Comment: @JoshBrody Weirdly enough, `.keys` is not available on the headers hash, I iterated over the hash instead. I solved the issue though and posted my answer below.

Comment: that was my next question :)

Comment: @JoshBrody Haha ^^ I figured the solution and went afk while typing the answer

Comment: For anyone else looking into this, request.headers is not a Hash, but a class, which is why `.keys` method is not available on it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, I wasn't able to access any headers which had an underscore in them directly, using the symbol or string representation. Upon iterating `request.headers` hash, I found that the headers sent in the request get prefixed with `HTTP_` after getting capitalised. So in my case, the  `access_token` header sent with the request can be accessed using  `request.headers[:HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN]` or `request.headers['HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN']` in the rails app.

However, if the header is in the form of a single word, like `kites`, it can be accessed directly using `request.headers[:kites]`.